# How to checkout all delta(*.~) files in git

Tags: git

I have made many commits included delta(*.~) files in git. Now I want to exclude delta files from all the commits. When I run `git rm abc.rb~` it delete `abc.rb` file

Comment: Shot in the dark: Escape the ~ ? `git rm abc.rb\~`

Comment: That would be *weird*. Usually `~` only has an effect at the start of a word...

Comment: What do you mean by "delta" files?

Comment: Delta files means temporary files

Comment: @VijayChouhan And how are they differentiated? Can you provide 2-3 example filenames that cover all the possible situations?

Comment: @Agis I have added 2 example of filenames
Ex: test.rb~
example.rb~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "exclude delta files from all the commits" (well, you could but that would require you to rewrite history and it's strongly disadviced).

However you can remove all files in a separate commit:

```
git rm *.*~
git commit -m "your message"
```

If you don't want these files in your repository you should add them to your `.gitignore` (https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files).

Comment: adding `echo *.~ > .gitignore` would be apt

Comment: @hus787 that would overwrite the current `.gitignore` if he had one

Comment: `echo *.~ >> .gitignore` would do then